# Screen flickers intermittently / regular interval Macbook pro 2019 touchbar

Tags: macos, mojave, screen, catalina, flickr

I upgraded my `Mac book pro 2019 touchbar` model to `Mojave` macOs. after upgrading i observed that my screen is flickering with a strip like formation. it will start and stop randomly. i tried all the fixes available around the internet but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily few days back i got an upgrade to`Catalina`. without wasting my time i upgraded the OS and now its been almost a week since that screen flickering has gone.

Ps. For all the software engineer folks. Even big giants like Apple also ships buggy software. so dont hesitate in writing buggy code ;-)